# How can I fill with the color and make it square using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to fill all the fluid with white colored square.
As you see the picture, each fluid is filled with white, but it's not complete square.
I wrapped whole with div class `WhiteZone`, but it won't make them square.
How can I make it square?

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EfwLj/)**

[image: This is not square!]

**HTML**

```
<div class="WhiteZone">
    <div class="Box">
        <div class="Left">
            abcdefg<br />
            opqrstu
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Box">
        <div class="Right">
            hijklmn
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.WhiteZone{
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}

div.Box{
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

div.Left{
    width: 300px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    clear: both;
}

div.Right{
    width: 300px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Clear your floats after "Box".

Comment: Are you saying that you simply want to have background set to white below `hijklmn` div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: table` for this. Write like this:

```
div.WhiteZone {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: table;
}

div.Box {
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EfwLj/2/).

Comment: Thanks this is what I wanted for my answer. But it messes when I tried to use border at the same time. Could you fix it and update? http://jsfiddle.net/EfwLj/6/

Answer (score 1):

```
div.WhiteZone{
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

You can add overflow:hidden to your whitezone class so it will stretch to fit the height of inner floating divs. But with only that added you will get white background taking full width of your page. Like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EfwLj/1/)

To avoid that, you can also add `float:left` to your whitezone class (like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EfwLj/3/)) or set a `width` to it (like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EfwLj/4/))